# Changing Range Slider background via Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the background color of a range slider via Javascript.

I'm not getting any errors, however the background color isn't changing at all. All the other values that change work, just not the background style.

```html
<input type="range" min="1000" max="6000" value="2000" step="100" class="slider" id="myRange" name="myRange"/>
```

```css
.slider{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(244, 237, 144) 60%, rgb(244, 237, 144) 60%);
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0.1px 10px -2px #000000;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('myRange').addEventListener('input', function(){sliderChange(this.value)});

function sliderChange(val) {
    document.getElementById('myRange').style.background = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117) ' + val + '%, rgb(244, 237, 144) ' + val + '%);';

    if (val == 6000) {
        var value = '6,000+';
    } else {
        var value = val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    document.getElementById('sqftValue').innerHTML = value;
    var base = val * 0.12;
    var discount = base * 0.2;
    var cost = base - discount;
    document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML = cost.toFixed(0);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the semi-colon from the end of the value you're setting it to.

`range.style.background =
'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117) ' + val + '%, rgb(244, 237, 144) ' + val + '%)';`

The value above should like this.

`range.style.background =
'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117) ' + val + '%, rgb(244, 237, 144) ' + val + '%)'`

```js
const range = document.getElementById('myRange')

range.addEventListener('input', function(){
  sliderChange(this.value)
});

function sliderChange(val) {
    range.style.background = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117) ' + val + '%, rgb(244, 237, 144) ' + val + '%)';
}
```

```css
.slider{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 60%, blue);
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0.1px 10px -2px #000000;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1000" max="6000" value="2000" step="100" class="slider" id="myRange" name="myRange" />
```

Also, using two percentage values doesn't do anything by the way.

Comment: Oh shit, you're right. I was trying to get two colors on each side of the range thumb.

Comment: @glitchbox that wasnt the issue. the issue is/was the semi-colon. for example, `style.background = 'red;'` isn't going to work because `'red;'` obviously isn't a valid color, just as any other value with a semi-colon at the end isn't a valid value.

Comment: @glitchbox but setting two different percentage values for the gradient isnt going to do anything. all you need is one percentage value for one of the sides. the percentage value just determines where the "split" or "middle" point is.

Comment: Yea I see that now. Thanks. Now I just gotta figure out how to convert the percentage since the value instantly fills the range.

Comment: @glitchbox you gotta somehow convert/translate the sliders values to hex format or u could try the 0-255 values. is there a reason youre using the 1000-6000 range?

Comment: yea, those values get placed in a div above the slider.

Comment: @glitchbox is there a reason youre using those particular values tho?

Comment: other than updating the text in the div above no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201360/discussion-between-bugwhisperer-and-glitchbox).

Comment: @glitchbox figured out how to make it smooth. heres the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/gOOWbMe?editors=1011). the caveat is that the color stop is always on one side of the knob